# Как из функции одного класса запустить функцию другого

Tags: python, ооп, kivy

```
class Quiz(Screen):
    def TextVkl(self): #Это нужно запустить
      global Ans, Ans2, Ans3, Ans4, text1
      def TextVkl2(Ans, Ans2, Ans3, Ans4, text1):
          self.ids.Label_text.text=text1
          self.ids.Ans.text=Ans
          self.ids.Ans2.text=Ans2
          self.ids.Ans3.text=Ans3
          self.ids.Ans4.text=Ans4
      TextVkl2(Ans, Ans2, Ans3, Ans4, text1)

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
     pass

kv = Builder.load_file("Quiz.kv")
class QuizApp(App):
  def TextV(self):
      Quiz.TExtVkl()#Вот тут ошибка, что прописать чтоб запустилась TextVkl?

  def build(self):
      return kv
```

Так вот мне надо чтобы TextV запускал функцию TextVkl, и чтоб она запускалась в классе Quiz

Comment: Нужно прочитать текст ошибки в первую очередь.

Answer (score 3):

Не устану повторять новичкам: **прежде чем использовать какие-то инструменты, разберитесь в них полностью!**

Теперь по существу: чтобы вызвать "функцию класса", которая по-хорошему называется методом, необходимо создать объект этого класса. Объясняется это тем, что класс – модель некоего объекта, а методы моделируют его поведение. Представьте класс "Собака". Чтобы услышать лай, нам нужна хотя бы одна собака. Вы же в своём примере пытаетесь услышать лай не от самой собаки а от абстрактного понятия о том, что такое вообще собака. Если проще, в ООП, чтобы что-то происходило, нужен тот, кто будет это делать, то есть, объект класса.

Если предыдущее было запутано и непонятно, вот пример проще. Классы и типы данных – во многом синонимы. Вы ведь не можете возвести в степень, например, тип `int`.

```py
print(int**2) # Так не сработает
```

Да, в этом примере оператор не работает немного по другой причине (Python распознаёт его как переменную и не находит объявления), но тем не менее смысл должен быть ясен.

Вы можете возвести число типа `int`  в степень, но сам тип – нет.

```py
i = 5 # Создали число типа int или ОБЪЕКТ КЛАССА int
print(i**2) # Сработает
```

Для программиста на C++ можно было бы привести гораздо более наглядные примеры, но я не уверен, что автор вопроса знает этот язык.

После объёмного вступления, наконец, решение Вашей проблемы:

```py
class Quiz(Screen):
    def TextVkl(self): #Это нужно запустить
        global Ans, Ans2, Ans3, Ans4, text1
        TextVkl2(Ans, Ans2, Ans3, Ans4, text1)

"""Вынес код метода отдельно, где ему самое место (это не имеет отношения к решению проблемы, описанной в вопросе)"""
    def TextVkl2(self, Ans, Ans2, Ans3, Ans4, text1):
        self.ids.Label_text.text=text1
        self.ids.Ans.text=Ans
        self.ids.Ans2.text=Ans2
        self.ids.Ans3.text=Ans3
        self.ids.Ans4.text=Ans4

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
     pass

kv = Builder.load_file("Quiz.kv")
class QuizApp(App):
    def TextV(self):
        q = Quiz() # Создаём ОБЪЕКТ КЛАССА  
        q.TExtVkl() # Вызываем метод ИЗ ОБЪЕКТА

    def build(self):
        return kv
```

P.S. Исключением из описанных мной правил являются статические методы, но переходить к их изучению стоит лишь усвоив основные принципы ООП.